# error.bars.by{psych} Multiple variables

Tags: r, psych

Hello Stack Community,

My question is in regards to the command

```
error.bars.by()
```

from the package `error.bars.by{psych}`.

I am familiar with how the command works:

```
 error.bars.by(
    mydata[3],
    mydata[1],
    by.var=TRUE,
    x.cat=TRUE,
    legend=5,
    eyes=FALSE,
    pch=10,
    cex=2,
    alpha=.05,
    density=10,
    )
```

My question is whether or not this command can handle two grouping variables.

If so, how would I code it?

The data table

```
   Group Subgroup  Measure
1      A        1 0.234213
2      A        1 0.046248
3      A        1 0.391376
4      A        2 0.911849
5      A        2 0.729955
6      A        2 0.991110
7      A        2 0.378422
8      A        3 0.898037
9      A        3 0.258884
10     A        3       NA
11     A        3 0.057631
12     A        3 0.745202
13     A        3 0.121376
14     B        1 0.385198
15     B        1 0.484399
16     B        1 0.115034
17     B        1 0.073629
18     B        1 0.456150
19     B        2 0.336108
20     B        2 0.845458
21     B        2 0.267494
22     B        3 0.536123
23     B        3 1.331731
24     B        3 0.505114
25     B        3 0.843348
26     B        3 0.827932
27     B        3 0.813351
28     C        1 0.095587
29     C        1 0.158822
30     C        1 0.392376
31     C        1 0.284625
32     C        2 0.898819
33     C        2 0.743428
34     C        2 0.298989
35     C        2 0.423961
36     C        3 0.868351
37     C        3 0.181547
38     C        3 1.146131
39     C        3 0.234941
```

Comment: martic, how did you put the code sections in the gray background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<something like>(TM)`:

```
error.bars.by( mydata[[3]], interaction(mydata[[1]], mydata[[other_col_name]]), by.var=TRUE,
             x.cat=TRUE, legend=5, eyes=FALSE, pch=10, cex=2, alpha=.05, density=10, )
```

The `interaction` function creates a new single column that can be used when you want a "long" version of a cross-classification. 
Edit:  <strike>I took out the by.var=TRUE since it wasn't documented on the help page for the function and you didn't describe what it was doing.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the help page I am referencing was <http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/psych/docs/error.bars.by>.


From my experimentation on R, the value would determine how the graph would look. I don't know how to post a picture so excuse me.

Comment: In regards to your suggestion @BondedDust, I have copy and pasted the command line response below: 


`> error.bars.by( mydata[[3]], interaction(mydata[[1]], mydata[[2]]),  
+              x.cat=TRUE, legend=5, eyes=FALSE, pch=10, cex=2, alpha=.05, density=10, )`


Console: `Error in if (by.var & (nvar > n.color)) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: Sorry. It might be needed and I do now see it listed. And maybe your error relates to my failure to read the parameter list carefully.

Comment: No worries, this might be a stretch here, but I was successful with `stripchart(Measure~Group,data=mydata,method="jitter",pch=19,jitter=0.1,col="black")` plotting with two categories. But as this is part of the base package of R. Is it safe for me to presume that third party packages such as {psych} are limited in the sense that if the original (coder?) did not include the ability to have multiple categories, it won't?

Comment: It really depends. The prototypical functions that handle multiple discrete variables as classifiers or stratifies are the regression functions, `aggregate`, `tapply`, and `ave`. If the help page for the function only uses a singular form of the word: "vector" or "factor" , then I'd take that as a strong suggestion that multiple classifiers were not anticipated.

Comment: I'm gonna have to backtrack and look up several words you used there. As to what you said about "singular" punctuation, all of the help pages and the {psych} manual itself are, unfortunately, singular. I wanted to thank you your time though! Gave me a couple of new things to learn today.

Comment: I didn't say anything about punctuation. The singular form of a noun in English generally has no "s". So when the Arguments section of the  help page says: `group: A grouping variable` the fact that it did not says "variables" can be taken as evidence that the author only wanted a single column vector to be specified. (It's sloppy documentation since it should have specified that the column be one of column number of column name, or possibly either if that were the way the function was written.)